# No Internet Connection Following CodeReady Containers VM Setup

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, virtualization, dnsmasq

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and am having trouble connecting to the internet. Network Manager indicates I'm connected to my wireless router, but there is a '?' symbol where the wifi symbol should be and I get a cannot find server error when I try to access web pages

My connection worked previously. Then, after setting up a virtual machine for a [Red Hat CodeReady Containers](https://code-ready.github.io/crc/#minimum-system-requirements-operating-system_gsg) installation, on subsequent restarts the above started happening. dnsmasq is used by the CodeReady Containers machine, but I don't know if that is relevant

Following @Crabtree's advice, I have confirmed that I can ping my wireless router's IP and 8.8.8.8. However, pinging my router by common name and google.com fails, so it appears to be a DNS issue. The CRC setup with libvirt uses dnsmasq. Perhaps that has changed something

Comment: Go to your settings > Network > Wifi > tap the ||| (rotated menu icon) and select known wifi networks. Find your network and select the cog - check IPV4 and IPV6, for now lets just make sure they're on automatic and weren't changed.

Comment: You can open terminal and run  ```ping -c 4 8.8.8.8``` See if you receive bytes!

Comment: From my experience with VM's - they create a virtual switch (like a gigabit network switch) for the VM to "plug into" and then your main computer is feeding the switch through the network you're using. Just to try to give you an analogy of what could be going on. You might be stuck in that virtual switch config. Try this out as well. ```sudo service network-manager restart```

Comment: Thanks @Crabtree . I checked the DNS entry in the Network-Manager GUI for my wireless network and it is blank. When I ping 8.8.8.8 in a terminal it gets a response with 0 packet loss. After using sudo service network-manager restart, the '?' icon changes to the wifi symbol in the top right corner, but accessing web pages still shows no server found, and on reboot the '?' is back again

Comment: I can ping my wireless router successfully by IP address, but when I use the common name I get service unknown, so I guess it is a dns issue. The libvirt crc VM used dnsmasq so maybe this has caused an issue. Not sure what the next steps are?

Comment: I'm not too sure about adjusting dns especially with the Red Hat installation and where they would be connected. I will do some searching.

Answer (score 0):

It did indeed turn out to be a DNS issue. [This post](https://labs.consol.de/devops/linux/2019/11/29/codeready-containers-on-ubuntu.html) by Markus Hansmair kindly explains the issue:

> This is where the subtle differences between Red Hat Linux and Ubuntu come into play. Both distributions use systemd and NetworkManager. But Ubuntu uses systemd-resolved for name resolution while Red Hat Linux uses dnsmasq.

So the dnsmasq setup that was created during CRC setup caused affected systemd-resolved. I followed Markus's advice and disabled systemd-resolved and removed the resolv.conf file. Now internet access and CRC are working.

It would be good if there was a way to run CRC on Ubuntu without having to disable systemd-resolved